# Angular decimal pipe dots formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular(4) decimal pipe but the dots is showing with numbers that have more than 4 digits, but with 4 digits the dot is not showing.

Example:

```
<td>USD {{amount| number: '1.2-2'}} </td>
```

14314,23123 returns 14.314,23

but

7157,11123 returns 7157,11
instead of 7.157,11

Is there any way of fixing it without making a custom pipe?

Comment: I am not able reproduce your issue, see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxqdhh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css). The pipe is working just fine. Please read the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'example'
})
export class Example implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number | string, locale?: string): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    }).format(Number(value));
  }
}
```

in your html:

```
 {{ amount| example}}
```

Comment: can you give me correct answer? @Clovis Ignacio Ferreira

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is probably related to active locale. Since Angular 5, a locale argument has been added to the decimal pipe. You can pass it and check the result.

Additionally, I created a simple example on [Stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxatsx) with a default locale and NG in version 4.4.7 - everything works as you needed, so try to debugging your current locale.

BTW. For cash presentation you can use `CurrencyPipe` instead `DecimalPipe` with hardcoded currency code.